# DocuSign Rest API integration in informatica cloud

Tags: docusignapi, informatica-cloud

I am using Docusign Login information api in a mapping with Informatica Cloud .
The mapping executes successfully with a fault response.The error message in the fault response is as follows.I have tested the same api in postman.I am using Integrator Key provided by Docusign  for authentication along with my username and password.The API works perfect in postman.But with Informtica Cloud it gives me following error.
I have created swagger file with username,Password and integrator key as headers for creating the web service in Informatica Cloud.I am using Authentication type as 'Basic' in the connector and in swagger file.Where I am I going wrong with authentication?The Integrator Key or the username and password are valid.

```
Unauthorized {

  "errorCode": "AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN",

  "message": "The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed."

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [question/answer](https://network.informatica.com/thread/82482) from the Informatica site may be of help.

If the Informatica Cloud connector enables you to pass an `X-DocuSign-Authentication` header then you can use DocuSign's Legacy authentication.

If not, then you will need to send an Authorization header with value `Bearer a_bearer_token`

From the Informatica QA, it looks like you will need to create a small application that will use the JWT Grant to create an Access Token, and then return the Access Token to Informatica.

Next, use the Access Token via Informatica to use DocuSign's API.

I'm sure that Informatica Cloud's consultants have come across this issue before, you could also contact them for help.

Comment: Thank you for X-DocuSign-Authentication header suggestion.It worked for login information.But now I am trying to use same authentication for moving an envelope from one folder to other using api.     PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/3557572/folders/d8e5fae7-1d07-4615-b24b-f1fde498f5b9     .It works in postman.But invalid token format"The security token format does not match the schema" error,while creating swagger file.

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign doesn't support Basic Authentication for API calls.

I'm not familiar with Informatica Cloud, are you able to define a custom header so you can properly provide the `x-docusign-authentication` data block?

Comment: Yest I am passing the header as {"Username":"{{username}}","Password":"{{password}}","IntegratorKey": "{{clientId}}"}.It is not able to generate a swagger file response in informatica swagger file generator.

Comment: Do I need to use a Json Web token Grant method for authorization or just an integration key should work?

Comment: What is the header name that's being passed? Typically with Basic Authentication set, the header name will be 'Authorization' which is incorrect for DocuSign's legacy header auth.

Comment: There is no header name that I have provided.I have just passed header in JSON format as shown above.

Comment: If you're not providing a header name and Informatica Cloud is following the standard for Basic Authentication (Described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), the header name provided will be `Authorization`. To use DocuSign's Legacy Header authentication, you must be able to define the header name as `X-DocuSign-Authentication`.